# VB Make a variable that calls other variables?

Tags: vb.net, variables, pointers, menu

I am working on a game in VB and have come up to an annoyance.

In the menu of my game there are buttons/sliders/toggles/textboxes that change the value of variables in the program - Ex: Brightness, toggle shadows, volume, etc...

For now in the 'ChangeVal()' function of these menu elements I have an if statement for the text of the element and accordingly change variables in the game. Would it be possible to make a magical system that allows me to specify what variable to change in the menu element's declaration?

```
Public Sub changeVal()
    'CHANGES VALUES OF VARAIBLES BASED ON TEXT
    Select Case text
        Case "Sound Effects" : Game.soundVolume = value
        Case "Music" : Game.musicVolume = value : For counter As Integer = 0 To Game.music.Count - 1 : Game.music(counter).sound.Volume = value / 100 : Next
        Case "Brightness" : Game.brightness = value
    End Select
End Sub
```

[image: A visual for the menu]

Comment: I haven't used VB since I became a free man, but would it not be better to have separate handlers for each button, individual changeVals() for each button? So Brightness has a changeBrightness() etc

Comment: Doing that would still require me to do something similar to what I am doing now. I do not declare each menu element one by one; they are defined in a class and I create them as I need them. My ultimate goal would be to give a "pointer" of sorts to the constructor of the element so I can tell the element what variable to affect when activated.

Comment: Have a look at polymoprphism and inheritance. This may sparc some ideas for you : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/akfttx8c(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: Either use [Events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms172877.aspx) or the [Strategy Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern). You might also be interested in [Delegates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms172879.aspx), which are basically variables that hold references to functions.

Comment: So far the best solution I have found is by declaring an object in the class for the menu elements. An object changes as the variable it is pointing to changes, but not the other way around. In this case would I want to make getters and setters for each variable I am trying to change remotely?